# Prove that Gal(Q(π):Q) is infinite

Tags: galois-theory

Good evening to everyone! 
I am trying for more than 2 hours to solve the next exercise in some lecture notes in Galois theory. The exercise has 2 parts and I managed to solve only part i) :

i) Prove that the group $ Gal(\mathbb{R : Q}) $ is trivial  (already proved)

ii) Prove that $ Gal(\mathbb{Q(\pi):Q})$ is infinite.

The second part is the one I cannot solve. As a hint, the author gives that for every $a\in \mathbb{Q}$ there exists $\sigma_{a} \in Gal(\mathbb{Q(\pi):Q})$ with $\sigma_{a}(\pi)=\pi+a$.

Does anyone have any idea ?

Thank you in advance for your time!

Comment: What do you need aside from the author's hint? There are clearly infinitely many $ a \in \mathbb Q $...

Comment: what does mean $Gal(\mathbb{R}:\mathbb{Q})$ is trivial ? That there is only one metric completion of $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 Trivial means that it contains only the identical isomorphism.

Comment: @Starfall Yes,I have to prove the hint only then.

Comment: @PetrosGreece yes I know, I'm asking how do you prove it, what property of $\mathbb{R}$ do you use

Comment: @user1952009 I have already proved the first part. Firstly, you show that if $a<b $ then $  \sigma(a)< \sigma(b)$. After that, if you suppose that $\sigma(k) \neq k $  for some $k \in \mathbb{R}$ this is contradiction,because always there is a $q$ between $\sigma(k)$ and $k$ and $\sigma(q)=q$.

Comment: @user1952009 Note that in $\mathbb{R}$, we have $a\le b$ iff $\exists c(c^2+a=b)$. Since the ordering is definable from the field structure, any field automorphism of $\mathbb{R}$ has to preserve the ordering. But any field automorphism of $\mathbb{R}$ has to fix the rationals, which are dense in $\mathbb{R}$; so the only field automorphism of $\mathbb{R}$ is the identity. Note that by contrast, this definition of the order does *not* work in e.g. $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$: $\pi\ge 0$, but $\sqrt{\pi}\not\in\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber  An interesting question would be also to show that $Gal(\mathbb{C:Q})$ is infinite. I thought this question last night, after this conversation.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the hint immediately implies that $Gal(\mathbb{Q}(\pi):\mathbb{Q})$ is infinite, since it contains $\{\sigma_a: a\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ (note that $a\not=b$ implies $\sigma_a\not=\sigma_b$ - do you see why?). So we only need to prove the hint.

To prove the hint, let's think about the structure of the field $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$. What does an arbitrary element of this field look like? Well, it's going to be a rational expression in $\pi$ - that is, something of the form $${a_k\pi^k+ . . . +a_0\pi^0\over b_m\pi^m+ . . . + b_0\pi^0}$$ with $a_i, b_j\in\mathbb{Q}$ (do you see why?).

OK, so now to prove the hint we need to do two things. Fix an $a\in\mathbb{Q}$; can you:

- Figure out what the automorphism $\sigma_a$ should do on an input like the expression above?
- Prove that the result is in fact a well-defined function, and a field automorphism of $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$ which fixes $\mathbb{Q}$ pointwise?

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. Yes I know that the elements of a general $\mathbb{Q}(a_1,...,a_n)$ are of the form $\frac{f(a_1,...,a_n)}{g(a_1,...,a_n)$ , where $f,g \in \mathbb{Q}(x_1,...,x_n)$. So,if we apply $\sigma_a$ to the above element, we will take $\frac{f(\sigma(\pi)}{g(\sigma(\pi))}$.

Comment: @PetrosGreece Yes. Do you see now how to prove the hint?

Comment: It is not obvious that $\sigma_a$ is an isomorphism ( you have to prove ,for example, that if $\sigma_a (t)= \sigma_a (s)$ then $ s=t $ and $ s,t $ are ''huge'' objects like the ones you mentioned above, not easy to show equality of coefficients etc..)

Comment: OK, I just proved that $\sigma_a$ is ONTO.(You take $F(x)=f(x-a), G(x)=g(x-a)$ and then $\sigma_a( \frac{F(\pi)}{G(\pi)})=\frac{f(\pi)}{g(\pi)}$). I am now stuck to show that $\sigma_a$ is 1-1...

Comment: OK,I just proved that also $\sigma_a$ is 1-1 !!! ( If $\sigma_a(s)=\sigma_a(t)$ then $\frac{f_1(\pi+a)}{g_1(\pi+a)}=\frac{f_2(\pi+a)}{g_2(\pi+a)}$ so $f_1 * g_2 - f_2 * g_1$ must be the zero polynomial, otherwise $\pi+a$ would be algebraic number,so $\pi$ would be algebraic, contradiction. So, $f_1(x)* g_2(x)= f_2(x) * g_1(x) , \forall x $ and this means that $\frac{f_1(\pi)}{g_1(\pi)}=\frac{f_2(\pi)}{g_2(\pi)}$ and $t=s$  ) .